# Can't reproduce "start/loop" behaviour in GenServer

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I'm trying to use a process as a synchronisation mechanism where it can receive messages our of order but still act properly. I've managed to implement simplified version of my problem with plain process, but I'm failing to achieve the same effect with GenServer.

The simplified version is like this:

```
defmodule Fun do
  def start_link do
    spawn(fn -> loop(:initiated) end)
  end

  def loop(state) do
    receive do
      :join when state == :initiated ->
        IO.inspect("Handling join")
        loop(:initiated)

      :finish when state == :initiated ->
        IO.inspect("Finishing")
        loop(:finishing)

      :cleanup when state == :finishing ->
        IO.inspect("Cleaning up...")
    end
  end
end
```

The above will process `:join` and `:finish` messages only when `state` is `:initiated`, and only perform `:cleanup` and exit when `:finish` has been received. Here I'm trying to take advantage of messages being stuck in mailbox until they can be matched.

It works like this:

```
iex(1)> pid = Fun.start_link
#PID<0.140.0>
iex(2)> send(pid, :join)
"Handling join"
:join
iex(3)> send(pid, :join)
"Handling join"
:join
iex(4)> send(pid, :cleanup) # No `IO.inspect` at this point
:cleanup
iex(5)> send(pid, :finish) # Two `IO.inspect`s once `:finish` received
"Finishing"
:finish
"Cleaning up..."
```

I was trying to reproduce same behaviour with GenServer:

```
defmodule FunServer do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, :initiated}
  end

  def handle_info(:join, msg) when msg == :initiated do
    IO.inspect("Handling join [From GenServer]")
    {:noreply, :initiated}
  end

  def handle_info(:finish, msg) when msg == :initiated do
    IO.inspect("Finishing [From GenServer]")
    {:noreply, :finishing}
  end

  def handle_info(:cleanup, msg) when msg == :finishing do
    IO.inspect("Cleaning up [From GenServer]")
    {:stop, :normal, msg}
  end
end
```

Given I configured my application with this GenServer as `:temporary` `worker` it works like this:

```
iex(1)> send(FunServer, :join)
"Handling join [From GenServer]"
:join
iex(2)> send(FunServer, :cleanup)
:cleanup
iex(3)>
07:11:17.383 [error] GenServer FunServer terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in 
FunServer.handle_info/2
    (what_the_beam) lib/fun_server.ex:22: FunServer.handle_info(:cleanup, :initiated)
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:616: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:686: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: :cleanup
State: :initiated
```

I've tried using `handle_cast` callbacks, and also different format of arguments, like:

```
handle_info(:cleanup, :finishing)
```

or

```
handle_cast(:cleanup, :finishing)
```

instead of `where msg == :finishing`, but none of them worked for me.

I'm using Elixir 1.5 with Erlang 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is called a selective recieve of regular erlang processes. This is a quote from Joe Armstrong's book:

```
    receive works as follows:
    ...
    2. Take the first message in the mailbox and try to match it 
    against Pattern1, Pattern2, and so on. If the match succeeds, 
    the message is removed from the mailbox, and the expressions 
    following the pattern are evaluated.
    3. If none of the patterns in the receive statement matches the 
    first message in the mailbox, then the first message is removed 
    from the mailbox and put into a “save queue.” The second message
    in the mailbox is then tried. This procedure is repeated until a 
    matching message is found or until all the messages in the mail- 
    box have been examined.
    4. If none of the messages in the mailbox matches, then the process 
    is suspended and will be rescheduled for execution the next time 
    a new message is put in the mailbox. Note that when a new message 
    arrives, the messages in the save queue are not rematched; only 
    the new message is matched.
    5. As soon as a message has been matched, then all messages that 
    have been put into the save queue are reentered into the mailbox 
    in the order in which they arrived at the process. If a timer 
    was set, it is cleared.
    6. If the timer elapses when we are waiting for a message, then 
    evaluate the expressions ExpressionsTimeout and put any saved 
    messages back into the mailbox in the order in which they 
    arrived at the process.
```

gen_server is not working this way. It needs your callback module to match a message or as you found out there is an error thrown because gen_server implementation is not finding a way to dispatch. If you want gen_server implementation to match the logic of receive as outlined above you will have to do it manually. A simple way would be to just accumulate all the messages you can not match in a given state in some sort of list and then resend them to self() after each successful match. For that your state can not be just a simple atom anymore because you will need to organize saved queue on your own.

And BTW this same question was asked before in context of erlang. The responder had a suggestion that is one to one with what I described. So if you need concrete code here is the link to that question: [How do you do selective receives in gen_servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290427/how-do-you-do-selective-receives-in-gen-servers)

Comment: Thanks for such an exhaustive answer. I didn't know about this optimisation - I had impression that the whole queue is re-evaluated when new message arrives (which was a basis for my first, successful attempt of solving the problem). What is the Joe's book you're quoting here?

Answer (score 3):

In your original code, your `receive` is ignoring the `:cleanup` message when the state is `:initiated`. This is a bad practice which can lead to a bottleneck as any such message will stay in the process's inbox forever, using up memory and also slowing down future `receive` blocks, since `receive` (usually) takes time proportional to the number of messages in the process's inbox.

`GenServer` handles this case correctly by forcing you to process messages in the order they're received. In order to ignore messages, you need to explicitly add a `handle_info` which does nothing. You can simply add this clause which will ignore `:cleanup` when state is `:initiated`:

```
def handle_info(:cleanup, :initiated), do: {:noreply, :initiated}
```

You can also instead just ignore any other message by adding this clause after all your existing `handle_info`:

```
def handle_info(_message, state), do: {:noreply, state}
```

---

> I've tried using handle_cast callbacks, and also different format of arguments, like:
>
> ```
> handle_info(:cleanup, :finishing)
> ```
>
> ...

If you read the stacktrace in the error message carefully, the problem is that `:gen_server` tried to call `FunServer.handle_info(:cleanup, :initiated)` but there was no clause defined in `handle_info` to handle that. There is no problem with `(:cleanup, :finishing)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I'm fully aware of the fact that if messages is not processed is put back to the mailbox, and how checking the mailbox works. I know, my app receives only one of this kind of `:finishing` messages in it's lifespan, then it dies. Based on that I started to model my solution around the problem of receiving messages out of ordered. This could be nicely solved "without GenServer" but wanted to replicate it inside "GenServer" so it pays nicely with OTP and supervision. Does it mean there is no way of replicating this behaviour at all?

Comment: Wouldn't adding the fallback `handle_info` clause (like shown in the answer) make this behave exactly the same as your original code? Your code also processes the messages in order, except that it ignores some messages based on the state.

Comment: Well, not exactly - `def handle_info(_message, state)` will discard the message, while in my first example, you can see `"Cleaning up..."` rendered *after* `"Finishing"`, even thou, `:cleanup` has been received *before* `:finish` messaged. `:cleanup` just politely waits in mailbox to be processed

Comment: Oh, now I get it. You're right. Well you can't make the gen_server hold messages like that as far as I know. If I had to use gen_server for this, I'd keep a boolean value in the state which stores whether `cleanup` has been called yet or not, and change the logic of the other handlers appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your effort in evaluating my problem! Thanks for final confirmation as it wasn't clear to me - why I was unable to achieve similar results with GenServer. I'll accept ash's answer as this one elaborates in more details about the problem I hit.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying to achieve is easier done with `:gen_statem` (or the Elixir wrapper library, found on hex as `gen_state_machine`). You can emulate selective receive with the use of the "postpone" capability, which will put the message back in to an internal buffer until the state of the machine changes, at which point postponed messages will be processed in the order they were received.

There are other nice tricks too like being able to generate "internal" messages which are placed at the head of the mailbox before anything else is handled. Since your example is a pretty clear cut case of an FSM, I'd recommend going that route rather than reinventing it in GenServer.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I didn't play with `gen_state_machine` just yet, but I've read through the documentation and it looks like really nice way of solving specific problem. I'll try to spike it in some more details in spare moment. For the time being I'm going to accept ash's answer as that one elaborates in more details about the problem I hit.